# How can I view the claims of the current user in an ASP.NET Trace?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, trace

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC application which uses the .NET 4.5 version of WIF to provide user identity. As those claims are being generated by a remote STS specific for that user, it's hard to test which claims are being received for a given user in an development environment.

What I would like is a mechanism that will allow me to see a user's claims by looking over their shoulder as they use the system. I immediately thought of the ASP.NET WebForms trace system as a source of tracing information and a convenient mechanism to display it, but I don't know of an equivalent in ASP.NET MVC.

Are there any built-in mechanisms to expose this information to me whilst debugging with a tester?

Comment: Are you asking how to dump this diagnostic data to the screen (i.e. a Q about trace frameworks) or are you asking how to get at the values that you want to dump to the screen (i.e. a Q about accessing STS values)?

Comment: A little of both. The claims are only valuable in the context of a user and for my situation that's most readily done by displaying the claims to the user they belong to. I can write a bespoke view and tap into the `ClaimsPrincipal` to do all that I need, but is there any existing plumbing to do the job for me in a standardised way?

Answer (score 1):

Options

[Glimpse](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx)- like webform inpage trage/trace.axd on steroids. Works nice for MVC apps, has little to offer webforms though (the team has been promising big things though, it's an area to watch).

trace.axd - Trace.Write output should appear here, I've never tried to run it on a busy server. Access to trace.axd should work for an mcv app, not sure if inpage trace works for mvc-- I would guess not but I have never tried.

<% "Some trace" %> -- I sometimes dump diagnostics to all screens and put it in the footer, or put it in the footer then make the text white on white, so I can instruct the user on how see it and copy it, but they won't normally see it.

System.Diagnostics TraceSource and associated classes -- It's better than Trace.Write but has some flaws if you use trace *a lot*. Still, there are scenarios when you can't assume your favorite trace/logging library will be available. If I were to use this, I'd write a custom listener and write to your user's diagnostic data to the database, or a file, listeners already exist for files.

Log4Net -- a trace/logging framework. Supports writing to a variety of places-- console, database, file, etc. Has fewer design flaws that System.Diagnostics, but requires adding noe more dependency to your app. Use same as System.Diagnostics -- log to a file or database and inspect your users STS values there.

I've never had the good fortune of using WIF or STS, but I imagine that pretty printing an object and it's properties is the same for much any object. You may want to post a WIF/STS question separately if you need to know how to extract a particular piece of info from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well - Trace.Write data shows up in the output window in VS while debugging. Maybe thats good enough. You can also add a trace listener for the System.IdentityModel trace source to get more insight into the token/claims processing.

Comment: It's not good enough, I'm afraid. If my users had Visual Studio, I'd just attach a debugger. The requirement is to see the information in the user output, like the ASP.NET WebForms tracing.